# SMS , flashlight, vibrate not working on codename one android build

Tags: codenameone

I have made an android app using [codename one](http://www.codenameone.com)

I tried the following with codename one:

1) Display.getInstance().flashBacklight(10);

2)Display.getInstance().vibrate(100);

3)Display.getInstance().sendsms();

All these API worked properly for the J2me build.

However, for android none of them worked. Why could this be happening? I tried it on motorolla atrix 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flashBacklight isn't supported on Android, if I remember correctly that functionality wasn't available on older Android versions it might be available now. You can file an issue on that and we can look into it again.

Vibrate should work its possible vibration was disabled on that specific device but I haven't tried it. You can file an issue on that as well and we can have a look.

Send SMS works for me, it opens up the SMS intent on Android and passes the text/number to which the SMS should be sent. This is different behavior than the J2ME version of sending SMS.

Comment: I put the sendSMS() method in a try catch block and displayed the exception in a dialog. I get a java.lang.securityException:Sending Sms Message: Neither user 10105 nor current process hass android permission.SEND_SMS.  How do I resolve this?

Comment: I just noticed a bug there which might also apply to vibrate. Since there are quite a few local changes I have it will take me a short while to update this but these should be working sometime next week. You can file an issue in the issue tracker if you want to keep track of this. Thanks.

Comment: sure...i'll file these issues :)